# How to Upload File to Google Drive via a Web Form Anonymously

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I need to implement a bug reporter form that users will be able to fill the form with additional information. Then this information will be posted to my google drive account as a text file.

I don't want users to be disturbed by any google drive or gmail permissions. I simply want my code to write file to my drive folder anonymously.

I made some investigation and I came up with google scripting as mentioned [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60843/anonymously-upload-to-my-google-drive). I created a custom web form to be filled and necessary gs(I guess this extension stands for google script) file.

I will not be able to add this form as an iframe because of cross domain, its url is something like 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxx...'. So I decided to open this form as a child browser tab, but that way I won't be able to pass bug message from parent to child.

Is there any way to send message from parent to child in this situation?
Is there any better way to implement this?

Thanks,
Ugurcan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are on the right track. using an apps script webapp is an easy way to avoid all the oauth permission code. I assume you have published to run "as me" with access to "everyone even anonymous".

there is no need to open as a child window. Simply pass all the data you need as url parameters to your webapp.
then on your app the parameters are received in doGet and use them to populate form fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different (non Apps Script) approach. Use a Service Account and upload to that account. Either share that account's files to your own account, or copy them to your own Google Dtive.

Comment: that requires a LOT more code and is not compatible with what he is asking (apps script)

Comment: A Service Account approach requires around 4 lines of code, and the question asked "Is there any better way to implement this".

Comment: hmm you might be right. but using a service account in apps script means not using DriveApp anymore and instead use advanced services and custom oauth. wouldnt it?

Comment: I've never used Apps Script to access Drive so I have no idea. My suggestion was meant to not use Apps Script. I've updated it to clarify.

Comment: ok but i suspect its not shats being asked. tag javascript would mean using node.js etc. its clear hes a beginner so thats too much burden.